# Changing association using nested attributes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-activerecord

I have a JSON api backend in Rails 4. I am trying to change an association using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

```
#models/section.rb
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :responsible, class_name: "User"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project, :responsible, allow_destroy: true
end

#controllers/api/section_controller
  def section_params
    params.require(:section).permit(:title, :body, :status, responsible_attributes: [:id], project_attributes: [:id])
  end
```

Part of the json related to the problem:

```
{
  section: {
    ...
    project_attributes: { id: 5 }
    responsible_attributes: { id: 2 }
    ...
  }
}
```

This ends up throwing `Couldn't find Project with ID=5 for Section with ID=84` on `Section.update_attributes(section_params)`. I guess that's because it's trying to find the associaton, except it doesn't exist because this is the way I'm trying to change it.

**My main question is:** is there a way of making the association change work using nested params? I'd like to do it this way instead of `:project_id` and `:responsible_id` to keep integrity of my client side models instead of having both `project: {:id, etc}` and `project_id:`.

I'm using a client-side serializer to convert the nested model names to have the `_attributes` suffix. Worst case scenario I will have to use that to append `project_id` and `responsible_id` to object being sent for updating.

Comment: which rails are you using? ..see [this](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3687-nested-attributes-with-belongs_to-only-supports-one-use-case)

Comment: Rails 4, I'm taking a look, seems like it is not intended to be used this way...